# How to add onBlur attribute to ZIP code field in Address Field

Tags: 7, commerce, javascript

In order to control the input format in the ZIP code field in the dynamic address fields provided by the Address Field module (I use it in Drupal Commerce) I need to add the attributes `onKeyUp` and `onBlur` to this field. My plan is to use Javascript to manage the formatting, but I need to add the above attributes first. How do I do that? I imagine I should use `hook_form_alter` in my template.php, but I could need a pointer on how to do it.

```
if($form['#id'] === "edit-customer-profile-billing-commerce-customer-address-und-0-postal-code"){
  dsm($form); // devel message does not show up in the checkout page in question
  $form['#attributes']['onBlur'] = '(this)'; 
}
```

EDITED: I have now managed to add the attributes this way:

```
  function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id === "commerce_checkout_form_checkout"){
      // Merge new attributes with existing ones.
      $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und']['0']['locality_block']['postal_code']['#attributes'] = array(
        'onBlur' => 'setZip(this)',
        'onKeyUp' => 'setLimit(this,5)',
      );
      $form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und']['0']['locality_block']['postal_code']['#attributes'] = array(
        'onBlur' => 'setZip(this)',
        'onKeyUp' => 'setLimit(this,5)',
      );
    }
  }
```

And this is the js script (I found it [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22482195/How-to-format-zip-code-using-javascript.html)):

```
(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            'use strict';
        var setZip, setLimit;
        console.log('outside');

        function setZip(theField){
          console.log('setzip');
          var num = theField.value.replace(/\D/g,"");
          theField.value = num.substr(0,3)+" "+num.substr(2);
        }

        function setLimit(theField, maxDigit){
          console.log('setlimit');
          var num = theField.value.replace(/\D/g,"");
          if(num>maxDigit){
            theField.value = theField.value.substr(0,maxDigit);
          }
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

The problem now is that I get a javascript reference error like this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setZip is not defined at
>   HTMLInputElement.onblur

I suspect this has something to do with the scope, so I have tried to place the js script with the setLimit and setZip functions in the header, in the body and in the footer, with the same error message. I also tried to remove the `$(document).ready(function()`... but the reference error reamins.

Any ideas?

Comment: The form ID will never be the HTML ID of an input buried somewhere in the form. The form alter has a `$form_id` param, use that to work out what the correct value is

Comment: Thanks, thanks to your pointer I now found out that the ID is commerce_checkout_form_checkout, but it does not seem to be an easy thing to add an attribute to a single field in this dynamic field group. I keep looking.

Comment: Yeah the checkout pane fields are really heavily nested

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this same problem. I have learned that it's a better practise to only use Javascript with an addEventListener to do this job, due to the scope rules.

This is how I finally did it. Change the code to adapt the formatting to the standard format in your country. This one changes the ZIP code format to five digits with a space inserted between digit 3 and 4.

```
  if($("#edit-customer-profile-billing-commerce-customer-address-und-0-postal-code").length){
    document.getElementById("edit-customer-profile-billing-commerce-customer-address-und-0-postal-code").addEventListener("blur", function(){
        if(this.value.length>5 && /\s/.test(this.value)){
          this.value = this.value.substr(0,6);
        }   else if(this.value.length>5 && !(/\s/.test(this.value))){
                        this.value = this.value.substr(0,5);
                    }
        if(this.value.length===5 && this.value.substring(3,4) !== " "){
            this.value = this.value.split(/(?=.{2}$)/).join(' ');
        }
    });
}
```